# Short circuit all() statement in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to short circuit an all() statement in Python?

So something like this:

```
return all([x != 0, 10 / x == 2, True, False, 7])
```

won't return an error if x is 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That doesn't work because the list (that is, all its items) is evaluated before `all` is even called. You best option in this particular case is something like this:

```
return x != 0 and 10 / x == 2 and True and False and 7
```

I assume you already know this, so I'll provide you with another, more general solution that can also be applied if the list items are not hardcoded:

```
return all(f() for f in [lambda: x != 0, lambda: 10 / x == 2, 
                         lambda: True, lambda: False, lambda: 7])
```

That way the expressions will only be evaluated within the short-circuit `all`.

Answer (score 6):

If your code were in a generator, then you could also short circuit stuff this way:

```
def test(x):
    yield x != 0
    yield 10/x == 2
    yield True
    yield False
    yield 7

all(test(9))
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't going to work exactly as you envision it, because Python evaluates all its function arguments before passing the resulting values to the function. In other words, it evaluates `10 / x == 2` down to a single value before calling `all`. (Contrast this with Mathematica, which will pass the unevaluated condition `10 / x == 2` and will do exactly what you want.)

The simplest thing to do, given that you know you're going to be passing this list to `all`, is to just use the short-circuiting capabilities of Python's `and` operator:

```
return all([x != 0 and 10 / x == 2, True, False, 7])
```

Alternatively you could rewrite the mathematical condition so that it doesn't divide by zero,

```
return all([x != 0, 10 == 2 * x, True, False, 7])
```

(watch out for floating-point division issues).

If you really want to emulate Mathematica's behavior of passing an unevaluated condition, though, the only way I can think of to do that is to pass a callable object which evaluates the condition when you call it. For example, you could convert all your list elements to lambda functions:

```
return all(f() for f in [lambda: x != 0, lambda: 10 / x == 2,
                     lambda: True, lambda: False, lambda: 7])
```

If you don't want to convert everything to a function, I guess you could come up with some sort of wrapper that will only call the things that are actually callable:

```
return all(f() if callable(f) else f in [x != 0, lambda: 10 / x == 2,
                                                  True, False, 7])
```

but honestly, that seems like a mess (unless you are writing a CAS in Python :-P).

Answer (score 1):

yes. If you want it to be false for x==0:

```
all([x != 0, x!=0 and 10 / x == 2, True, False, 7])
```

just make sure each value is allowed for any value x.